# Access to shared folder from local network

Tags: shared-folders

I am using Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04 both connected on the same Wi-Fi.

I need to be able to share files from win to Ubuntu and vice versa.

I am trying to follow the steps [here](https://itsfoss.com/share-folders-local-network-ubuntu-windows/) which seems every straighforward but when I try to add network location, a window security pops up and asks for credentials (username and password). I have tried to enter my Ubuntu login username and password but it did not work.

[image]

What are these credentials that I am asked to enter? Is it something I need to figure out from my Ubuntu machine or on my win?

Comment: Did you follow the point 1 (guest user) or did you try the 'Samba' way (point 2).  In the first case, did you try just hitting 'Enter', without entering further info?

Comment: Yes, You are right I had samba set up but I forget the password so what I did is followed the interactions here `https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-and-configure-samba#4-setting-up-user-accounts-and-connecting-to-share` and rest the password to new password.